# android javamail api does not use specified port (STARTTLS)

Tags: android

I try to send an eMail via smtp and STARTTLS encryption.
My Code:

```
Properties emailProperties = new Properties();  
emailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", emailHost); 
emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
emailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", emailPort);  
Log.i("GMail", "Mail server properties set.");
mailSession = Session.getInstance(emailProperties, this);
mailSession.setDebug(true);
```

When I call Transport.send(...) I get the following Log-entries:

```
09-13 11:10:23.293: I/System.out(2483): DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
09-13 11:10:23.293: I/System.out(2483): DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.web.de", port 465, isSSL true
09-13 11:10:30.323: E/GMail(2483): Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.web.de, port: 465
09-13 11:10:30.323: E/GMail(2483): javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.web.de, port: 465;
09-13 11:10:30.323: E/GMail(2483):   nested exception is:
09-13 11:10:30.323: E/GMail(2483):  java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to smtp.web.de/213.
```

My web.de server requieres the port 587. But javamail ignors the settings and try to connect at port 465. When I use `mail.transport.protocol="smtps"` then it uses port 587 but then I get an protocolException.